# LibGDX Scene2D acting odd to multi-touch

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

So I've recently been abusing Google for an answer, however just can't find one, and my head's starting to ache. I've recently released my second game on the Google Play Store, and only now have I been getting feedback that the people aren't too crazy about the button pressing mechanics (same mechanics as the first game). My game can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.towersvault.laddergoat2) if you want to give it a go, unfortunately I don't have an HTML version hosted elsewhere.

Making the game, I used `LibGDX`, and for the UI, I've used `Scene2D` that comes with `LibGDX`. My game requires that you press the green "bug" button to get a point (the "bug" buttons cycle around at random), you are forced to play against a timer, so you would obviously want to go faster for a higher score (think Piano Tiles).

Now, to the problem at hand, one of the game modes in my new game is called "Zen", two buttons, one gives you 1 point, the other 2 points. The problem I'm experiencing is that if you hold both "bug" (bottom right and bottom left) buttons down, and release one of the buttons, the released one triggers a score increase, and the other button resets as if it was never pressed on in the first place (even if your finger is still on it). Here's the code for my `Scene2D` buttons (working off memory, don't have my code near me at the moment):

```
// All is initialized correctly, no crashes, here's the part about the listener.
leftBugButton.addListener(new ChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)
    {
        // Run code here when button has been released.
    }
}

// And the right hand button's code. Initialization is perfect, no problems.
rightBugButton.addListener(new ChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)
    {
        // Run code here when button has been released.
    }
}
```

Getting to my question, what I want to go for is that if a button press has been completed (pressing and then releasing), I don't want the other buttons to reset to an unpressed state.

Any tips, or perhaps a different `Listener` I should use, or even dumping Scene2D for these buttons (using sprites with `InputListener` for example)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

TV

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ChangeListener for that, use a ClickListener (button.addClickListener(new ClickListener...)) and handle your process on touchUp event, ChangeListener gonna process if **ANYTHING** on the button change and it's not a good approach to handle a button release event.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, have started changing my buttons over to ClickListener. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, I kept rebuilding the `Stack` after every button press, resulting in the odd behavior, opted instead for a `.setStyle()` on my buttons which is working a lot better.